# Any possible way to build arrays in one single line for http_build_query function?

Tags: php

Is there any possible way to dynamically build array in one single line to use it inside http_build_query function?

This would be one of scenarios:

```
//1. Initial array state
$array = array('value1' => 1);

//2. Clicks on "Sort by name ASC"
$array = array('value1' => 1, 'sort' => array('name' => 'ASC'));

//3. Clicks on "Sort by timestamp DESC"
$array = array('value1' => 1, 'sort' => array('name' => 'ASC', 'timestamp' => 'DESC'));

//4. Clicks on "Sort by name DESC"
$array = array('value1' => 1, 'sort' => array('name' => 'DESC', 'timestamp' => 'DESC'));

//5. Clicks on "Sort by timestamp ASC"
$array = array('value1' => 1, 'sort' => array('name' => 'ASC', 'timestamp' => 'ASC'));
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
http_build_query(array_merge($arr, array('sort' => array('email' => 'ASC'))));
http_build_query(array_merge($arr, array('sort' => array('timestamp' => 'ASC'))));
```

But of course, every time I use this line with different values, everything in $arr['sort'] is overwritten and only single value is kept there.

Comment: Take a look at [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) does it do what you want?

Comment: Add values based on post or get parameters from frontend or use sessions to remember previous choices on the server.

Comment: Values are based on $_GET parameters.

Comment: @TomsEglite So what do you see with print_r($_GET)  each time?

Comment: It's always one single value. For example if I sort by name DESC I get sort%5Bname%5D=DESC , if i click sort by timestamp ASC, I get sort%5Btimestamp%5D=ASC

Comment: @TomsEglite I believe the decoding should happen automatically when you receive in PHP. What do you see exactly with `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: Array ( [sort] => Array ( [timestamp] => ASC ) )  if I sort by time ASC,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use sessions since you only send one parameter at a time. So, add a `session_start()` to all PHP files in your project. Set `sort` key inside the session and set the type values whenever you receive them. This way, previous choices are remembered until you explicitly destroy the session or unset the keys.

```
<?php

session_start();


/* 
 * Add additional isset checks for get parameters
*/


$sort_type = $_GET['sort'];
$sort_key  = array_keys($sort_type)[0];
$_SESSION['sort'][$sort_key] = $sort_type[$sort_key];

echo http_build_query(['sort' => $_SESSION['sort']]);
```